# API to delete multiple offline agents from Azure DevOps

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Our Azure DevOps build agents are setup on Kubernetes. Failed pods can easily be deleted from kube, but they appear as "offline" agents from the Azure DevOps Web UI.

Overtime the list of offline agents has grown really long. Is there a way to programmatically delete them ?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206874/azure-devops-rest-api-get-builds-currently-queued-in-agent-pool

Answer (score 1):

```
$agents = Invoke-RestMethod -uri 'http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/29/agents' -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials
$agents.value |
    Where-Object { $_.status -eq 'offline' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-RestMethod -uri "http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/29/agents/$($_.id)?api-version=4.1" -Method Delete -UseDefaultCredentials
    }
```

Some assumptions for this solution:

1. You are looking for build agents
2. You know the id of the pool you are looking for already.  You can get to this programatically also, or just loop through all pools if you want
3. You don't have any issues deleting any offline agents

**Note:**  I'm using Azure DevOps Server, so replace the `-UseDefaultCredentials` with your authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use a combination of these 2 api calls:

1. [Get deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
2. [Delete agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: Not sure how to get a deployment group id, so I tried to list them, that came back with 0 results :\

Comment: hm, try [agentclouds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agentclouds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) get or list

Comment: that's returns a 404

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use some naming matrix for agents, so they are using the same "name" even if it is not the same container.

https://github.com/julioct/azure-pipelines-kubernetes-agents