# Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.1 API - How to get a build including the agent it ran on

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using an instance of `BuildHttpClient` of the nuget package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` to get my builds. Unfortunately the fetched objects of type `Build` do not include the name or id of the agent used to ran the build.

The property `Queue` just contains informations about the used queue, but not about the specific agent. There's another property `AgentSpecification`, but this seems to be always empty.

I could probably parse the attached logs of a build, but that would be pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's an issue. However, as a workaround, you can try to extract that information from the logs. Small example:

```cs
var logs = BuildClient.GetBuildLogsAsync(TeamProjectName, buildId).Result;

foreach(var log in logs)
{
    var lines = BuildClient.GetBuildLogLinesAsync(TeamProjectName, buildId, log.Id).Result;

    foreach (var line in lines)
        if (line.Contains("Agent")) Console.WriteLine(line);                    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already implemented it that way, but then I found out, that the logs are gone as soon as somebody deletes a build. Because I wanna do a daily "snapshot" of how many, when and how long builds have been ran, I went with another approach. I found out, that you can get all job requests of the agents with an api call ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206874/azure-devops-rest-api-get-builds-currently-queued-in-agent-pool)). Because the job requests contains the build id, you can ref them.